# How much would an ubuntu tablet cost? Where could I find one?

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-touch, tablet

I know that Canonical will produce Ubuntu tablets, and I'd buy one, but I don't know how much would it cost and where will I find it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link provided on the Tablet page of www.ubuntu.com that will allow you to sign up for a notification about updates to the Ubuntu Tablet: http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet/register

If you cannot wait until an unspecified date, you could modify a Nexus 7 (or Nexus 10) which would cost $199 or greater. 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation

*Note this installation is a preview, not what the final OS will be. There is more information on the Developer Preview. Expect bugs.